# how to loop through 3 files , search for a specific string and match it to a string in another file using bash

Tags: linux, bash, delimiter, do-while

i hav 3  text files which i hav to use for the following code. these are : subscribers.txt ,towns.txt & calls.txt .[their link is http://www.cs.ub.bw/teaching/csi223 :](http://www.cs.ub.bw/teaching/csi223)

**Subscribers.txt** has the format:

```
 callerID|name |gender|birthYear|hometownID|email
 10000025|kgosi|F     |1981     |33        |10000025@cs.ub.bw
```

**Town.txt** has the format :

```
hometownID|townName   |location
28        |Ramatlabama|B
```

**calls.txt** has the format:

```
date      |time    |duration|calleeID|callerID|locationOfcallee|locationOfcaller
18/02/2005|19:25:27|257     |10000025|10000017|3               |28
```

i created a function that takes a callerID as a parameter then print out the calls sent out by that callerID.how do i modify the following code such that it  the read the callerID from the keyboard,display all calls of that callerID.the first line before displaying all calls must contain: callerID,name(from the subsribers.txt),age(take the birthYear from   subscribers.txt and calculate age),gender(from subscribers.txt)and townName(from towns.txt)

THE CODE IS ::

```
 #!/bin/bash

    echo "enter caller id "
    read  x
    exec 401<> calls.txt       # open calls.txt file  
    exec 402<> subscribers.txt #opens  subscribers.txt
    exec 403<> town.txt #opens tows.txt
    while  read line <&402 #reading from subscribers.txt
    do
    {



        callerid=${line%%|*}; # cut off the rest of $line but keep callerid
        line=${line#*|};       

        name=${line%%|*}; # cut off the rest of $line but keep time of name
        line=${line#*|};      e



        gender=${line%%|*};  # cut off the rest of $line but keep box
        line=${line#*|};       

        year=${line%%|*};   # cut off the rest of $line but keep town
        line=${line#*|};      


        hometown=${line%%|*};   # cut off the rest of $line but keep phone
        line=${line#*|};     


        email=${line%%|*};   # cut off the rest of $line but keep email
        line=${line#*|};



    if [ $callerid = "$x" ]
    then 

        echo $callerid "|" $name "|" $gender "|" $hometown ;
     echo " $callerid "|" $name "|" $gender "|" $hometown">>${x}outgoingcalls.log #stores in this file

    fi

    }
    done
    exec 402>&-


    while read line <&401      # read a line at a time from calls.txt
    do                         # if end of file reached, while will yield false then terminate
    {
        full_line=$line;       # because $line is going to change, store it somewhere


        date=${line%%|*}; # cut off the rest of $line but keep date  
        line=${line#*|};      



        time=${line%%|*}; # cut off the rest of $line but keep time    
        line=${line#*|};       



        duration=${line%%|*};  # cut off the rest of $line but keep duration
        line=${line#*|};       



        callee=${line%%|*};   # cut off the rest of $line but keep callee
        line=${line#*|};      


        caller=${line%%|*};   # cut off the rest of $line but keep phone
        line=${line#*|};      

        ### extract phone
        calleeLoc=${line%%|*};   # cut off the rest of $line but keep callee location
        line=${line#*|};



        ### extract phone
        callerLoc=${line%%|*};   # cut off the rest of $line but keep caller location
        line=${line#*|};

        if [ $caller = "$x" ];
          then

                 echo $date"|"$time"|"$duration"|"$callee"|"$caller"|"$calleLoc"|" $callerLoc
            echo "$date:$time:$duration:$callee:$caller:$calleeLoc:$callerLoc>>${x}outgoingcalls.log #stores in this file
        fi


    }
    done


    exec 401>&-
```

Comment: Do you really wanna do this in pure bash? Maybe check out http://pythonhosted.org//querycsv/ . `Querycsv` gives you the possibilty to use SQL queries on CSV Files.

Answer (score 1):

Your script is processing every single line of the calls and subscribers before matching against the given input. It would be more sensible to use grep to find the relevant lines before processing them.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "Enter caller id: "
read caller_id

caller_details=$(grep -m 1 "$caller_id" subscribers.txt)

caller_name=$(echo $caller_details | cut -d\| -f2)
caller_age=$(($(date +%Y)-$(echo $caller_details | cut -d\| -f4)))
caller_town=$(grep -m1 "$(echo $caller_details | cut -d\| -f5)" towns.txt | cut -d\| -f2)

printf "Caller ID: %s | Name: %s | Age: %s | Town: %s\n" "$caller_id" "$caller_name" "$caller_age" "$caller_town"
echo "==================================================================="
printf "%-10s | %-8s | %-3s | %-16s | %-16s | %-16s | %s\n" "Date" "Time" "Dur" "Callee" "Caller" "Callee Town" "Caller Town"

for call in $(awk -v id="$caller_id" -F'|' '$5==id' calls.txt); do
    call_date=$(echo "$call" | cut -d\| -f1)
    call_time=$(echo "$call" | cut -d\| -f2)
    call_duration=$(echo "$call" | cut -d\| -f3)
    callee=$(grep -m 1 "$(echo "$call" | cut -d\| -f4)" subscribers.txt | cut -d\| -f2) 
    callee_town=$(grep -m1 "$(echo "$call" | cut -d\| -f6)" towns.txt | cut -d\| -f2)
    caller_town=$(grep -m1 "$(echo "$call" | cut -d\| -f7)" towns.txt | cut -d\| -f2)
    printf "%s | %s | %-3s | %-16s | %-16s | %-16s | %s\n" "$call_date" "$call_time" "$call_duration" "$callee" "$caller_name" "$callee_town" "$caller_town"
done
```

Sample output:

```
$ ./test
Enter caller id: 10000010
Caller ID: 10000010 | Name: Daniel,R B | Age: 34 | Town: Gaborone
===================================================================
Date       | Time     | Dur | Callee           | Caller           | Callee Town      | Caller Town
01/06/2005 | 14:58:31 | 250 | Makwati,T.M.     | Daniel,R B       | Gaborone         | Tonota
02/03/2005 | 16:31:37 | 622 | Matshameko,T.C.  | Daniel,R B       | Francistown      | W. Mohembo
02/09/2005 | 10:58:28 | 295 | Khetho,P         | Daniel,R B       | Gaborone         | Gaborone
03/01/2005 | 20:06:26 | 325 | Tladi,Og         | Daniel,R B       | Kang             | Gaborone
03/07/2005 | 15:18:40 | 263 | King,W           | Daniel,R B       | Nokaneng         | Gaborone
etc...
```